# r error: Complex matrix?

Tags: r, filter, error-handling, smoothing

I'm trying to smooth my data using Savitzky-Golay filter, but I keep getting an error in R-Studio:

```
Error in La.svd(x, nu, nv) : 'a' must be a complex matrix
```

even when running the example code:

```
library(pracma)
ts <- sin(2*pi*(1:1000)/200)
t1 <- ts + rnorm(1000)/10
t2 <- savgol(t1, 51)
```

or:

```
library(signal)
bf <- butter(5,1/3)
x <- c(rep(0,15), rep(10, 10), rep(0, 15))
sg <- sgolayfilt(x)
```

The error doesn't appear when I run the same thing in R. What might be the problem?

Comment: I tried the code in R 3.2.2. and in R studio Version 0.99.467.  It worked in both.

Comment: I have R 3.2.2 RStudio 0.99.473

Comment: Some possible bugs in that version?

Comment: How to force the update of R-Studio, it says that I'm running the newest version?

Comment: It may be the newest version.  Here is the [Rstudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us).  You may also post the problem there if you don't get a response.

Comment: I'm running RStudio 0.99.473 (which is indeed the latest version) and your code ran without an error on my Mac running OSX Yosemite. It might be a bug in RStudio, but could it be that you have other packages loaded in your RStudio session that are interfering with `pracma` or `signal` in some way? What happens when you run your code in a clean RStudio session with only those two packages loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and upgraded my R-studio from 0.98 to 0.99 and this fixed the "Error in La.svd(x, nu, nv) : 'a' must be a complex matrix" problem.